# Getting NaN(Not a Number) in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wanted to make a little gas calculator in Flash with AS but i am getting the error "NaN" in my textfield even BEFORE i enter anything inside the textfield. Any ideas where the problem is? Many thanks in advance. Here is my actionscript code:

```
km_txt.restrict = ".0-9";
liter_txt.restrict = ".0-9";
priceliter_txt.restrict = ".0-9";
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,  calculate);

        function  calculate(param1:Event)
        {
            if (liter_txt.text != "" && km_txt.text != "")
            {
                usage_txt.text = String(100 * Number(liter_txt.text) / Number(km_txt.text));
            }

            if (liter_txt.text != "" && km_txt.text != "" && priceliter_txt.text != "")
            {
                cost_txt.text = String(Number(liter_txt.text) / Number(km_txt.text) * Number(priceliter_txt.text));
            }

            if (liter_txt.text != "" && priceliter_txt.text != "")
            {
                total_txt.text = String(Number(liter_txt.text) * Number(priceliter_txt.text));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why on earth do you use an `ENTER_FRAME` `Event` here? It only makes sense to do those calculations if the `.text` properties in the textfields have changed. Listen for changes on the textfields!

Answer (score 2):

You are casting to Number a few times from TextField objects but those at that point don't contain anything so the cast resolve to NaN:

```
String(100 * Number(liter_txt.text) / Number(km_txt.text));
```

Now trying to add/multiply/divide Number and NaN together still resolve to NaN.

You need to check for value first and maybe set to 0 if you get NaN, store in variables to make things easier:

```
var value:Number = Number(liter_txt.text);
if(isNaN(value))
{
    //this is not a number so substitute with 0?
    value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure about initial text values of your input TextFields since you are checking value of "". At the top of your block, write;

```
km_txt.text = "";
liter_txt.text = "";
priceliter_txt.text = "";
```

And it will be a better code if you listen to TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT events on TextFields and make calculations there.